# AWS Amplify - React Authenticator Components not visible

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

Building an Authentication UI with https://aws-amplify.github.io/media/ui_library

```
import { Authenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react'
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';

Amplify.configure(aws_exports);

const AppWithAuth = () => (
 <Authenticator />
)
```

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#using-the-authenticator-component-directly

Using React Developer Tools to inspect, Components are visible in React View

[image]

But not in DOM view of Browser
[image]

so, the various components of Authenticator like Greetings and SignIn are not showing up in DOM. How do you make them visible in Browser

[[Auth and AuthData state after logging in][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEFhf.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEFhf.png)

[[Console.logs][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p1wr.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p1wr.png)

Comment: Hi Shorn Jacob! Have you managed to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The components render UI or nothing base on `authState` property. In your case `authState` is `signedIn`. So only `Greetings` would render some UI.

Comment: <Authenticator >
      <Greetings/>
    </Authenticator> is not rendering Greetings UI even when authState is signedIn.

Comment: How about try this. In your code add
    import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
    import aws_exports from './aws-exports';

    Amplify.configure(aws_exports);
    Auth.signOut()

This is to make sure you are signed out. Then sign in form should show up.

Comment: Had tried this. This forces the Login Form. but once signedIn, No greetings is displayed.

Comment: Looks like there is only `authState` but no `authData` in components, which would cause an error in `Greetings`. Did you check console log? Is there any error logs?

Comment: I have added screenshots of authData and console.log

Answer (score 1):

> the various components of Authenticator like Greetings and SignIn are not showing up in DOM.

Seeing that your `authState` is currently at `signedIn`, you are literally already signed in. That's why the `<SignIn>` component is not visible/rendered.  If you want to see the `<SignIn>` component working, your `authState` should be in `"signIn"` value, and you can try to hard-code it as an initial state for seeing it in action.

```
import React from "react";
import { Authenticator } from "aws-amplify-react";
import Amplify from "aws-amplify";
import aws_exports from "./aws-exports";

Amplify.configure(aws_exports);

const AppWithAuth = () => (
  <Authenticator
    // Optionally hard-code an initial state
    authState="signIn"
  />
);
```

As for the `<Greetings>` it should show up if your state is `signedIn`. You can alternatively try using the `withAuthenticator` Higher Order Component.

```
import React from "react";
import { withAuthenticator } from "aws-amplify-react";
import Amplify from "aws-amplify";
import aws_exports from "./aws-exports";

Amplify.configure(aws_exports);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello world!</h1>
      <p>This is your own App Component</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default withAuthenticator(App, {
  // Render a sign out button once logged in
  includeGreetings: true
});
```